# Sort HTML list alphabetically in PHP

Tags: php, html, html-lists

I have a website that contains a manual with many office precedents. When a user uses the HTML upload script it uploads the precedent to a folder on the server. I use the following script to list out all the files in that specific folder.

```
<?php  //define the path as relative
  $dir = "./OFFICE PRECEDENTS/Business & Corporate Law"; 
  $webpath ="";  //using the opendir function  
  echo "<ol>";    
  // Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents   
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {     
  while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {   
  if (is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)){}      
  else if ($file == '.'){}      
  else if ($file == '..'){} 
  else if ($file == 'index.php'){}     
  else {      
  echo "<li><a href='https://manual.malicki-law.ca/$dir/$file'>$file</a></li>\n";      
  }    
  }       
  closedir($dh);     
  } 
  echo "</ol>";     
  ?>
```

How can I implement a system to alphabetically sort the list?

Comment: Have you tried saving the file details into an array, sorting it, and then displaying that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific case: If you use `scandir()` instead of `readdir()`, the default order is already in alphabetical order.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

The second parameter is:

> **sorting_order**
>   By default, the sorted order is alphabetical in
>   ascending order. If the optional sorting_order is set to
>   SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING, then the sort order is alphabetical in
>   descending order. If it is set to SCANDIR_SORT_NONE then the result is
>   unsorted.

So instead of:

```
 if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {     
   while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {   
       // your code   
    }    
  }       
  closedir($dh);
```

Just use something like:

```
if ($files = scandir($dir))
{
    foreach ($files as $file) {
       // your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should help you:

natcasesort: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php

usort: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php with a comparator function that compares strtolower(a) and strtolower(b)

You need to create an array first.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Save it into an array, but then instead of a numerical key, use an alpha-numeric one. Then you should be able to use a sort function on the keys and your values change to the correct order. Then just iterate over the array and echo them back out again.

For more info on sorting arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$my_array = array("a" => "Dog", "b" => "Cat", "c" => "Horse");

sort($my_array);
print_r($my_array);
?>
```

or You can use: asort, rsort, arsort

Answer (score 0):

Many ways todo this, [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) is also good, then you dont have to worry about directory's.

```
<?php 

$dir = "./OFFICE PRECEDENTS/Business & Corporate Law/";

$files = glob($dir."*.*");
sort($files);//Sort the array

echo "<ol>";
foreach($files as $file){
    if($file == $dir.'index.php'){continue;}
    $file = basename($file);
    echo "\t<li><a href='https://manual.malicki-law.ca/$dir/$file'>$file</a></li>\n";
}
echo "</ol>";
?>
```

Comment: I think glob may have a performanec issue, when used on directotries with many files. I can't remember where I read this.

Comment: Ive used glob with directory's with 10k odd files and not noticed an issue, but i would also add a cache of sorts so the operation would only need tobe done when the directory changes.